# restbed make install in raspberry-pi undefined reference to dlopen dlclose

Tags: raspberry-pi, dlopen, restbed

I'm very inexperienced in raspberry and raspbian OS.

I'm trying to install restbed library in a raspberry-pi.

When I do

```
    make install
```

it doesn't work and I get the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/restbed/build $ make install
[ 17%] Built target restbed-static
[ 17%] Built target restbed-shared
[ 17%] Linking CXX executable service_unit_test_suite
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup': 
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `dlopen'  
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `dlsym' 
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `dlsym'  
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':  
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x334): undefined reference to `dlclose'  
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':  
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `dladdr'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x464): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x62c): undefined reference to `dlclose'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
test/unit/CMakeFiles/service_unit_test_suite.dir/build.make:97: recipe for 
target 'test/unit/service_unit_test_suite' failed  
make[2]: *** [test/unit/service_unit_test_suite] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:177: recipe for target 
'test/unit/CMakeFiles/service_unit_test_suite.dir/all' failed  
make[1]: *** [test/unit/CMakeFiles/service_unit_test_suite.dir/all] Error 2  
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make: *** [all] Error 2

pi@raspberrypi:~/restbed/build $
```